# Can I import to a subversion repository without importing the parent folder

Tags: svn

I'm sure I'm missing something but I'm a bit out of practice with subversion.

Say I've got a folder full of files:

```
 /projectname/index.html
 /projectname/img/a.jpg
 /projectname/img/b.jpg
```

and I want to import the whole thing to subversion, I can do `svn import <foldername> <repository>` but when I do that I import not only the index.html and the images, but also the parent `projectname` folder. So when I want to check it out, I'm going to be checking out that folder too.

Is there a way to import the folder *contents* but not the folder? So that a checkout would put only the index.html and the img folder into whichever folder I was doing the checkout to? Or do I have to import the files and folders one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no...

When you use `svn import`, you are importing a directory (aka folder). Subversion considers directories as project locations, and Subverion import is for importing projects.

However, you don't have to use `svn import`:

```
$ svn co --depth=immeidates $REPO/trunk  # Checkout the location for project
$ cd trunk                               # Go into that directory
$ cp -R /projectname/* .                 # Copy the files into that SVN workspace
$ svn add -R .                           # Recursively add in a project
$ svn commit -m"Added files to trunk"    # And, you're done!
```